# I am not able to setup my meteorup.

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

When I am typing "mup setup" in cmd, it is throwing the following error as shown in the picture.
[image]

I do not know what to do. I am using my college's network. It was working a week back or so(the last time I tried to deploy my website).
Apologies for any mistakes in posting the question.

Comment: It seems the connection is blocked :)

Comment: How do I rectify it?